# What default port does WCF use for nettcp when hosted by IIS?

Tags: wcf, iis, nettcpbinding

Our server is WCF based and it is hosted by IIS. We use nettcp as our binding. The app is working but we still have one thing unclear to us: Since we are not specifing a port # in our configuration, what is the default port that WCF/IIS uses? In production environment, do we need to manually open a port in IIS for WCF/NetTcp?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default port is 808. You can learn more about it here: [How to: Configure a Windows Communication Foundation Service to Use Port Sharing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731810.aspx).

Make sure you open port in firewall.