# Is it possible to host both web/SignalR and WCF w/ netTcpBinding in a single web-role?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-web-roles

We have binary `WCF` service (`netTcpBinding`) in a web-role and an `asp.net` website (to take advantage of `SignalR` over azure's backplane). Due to the extremely low budget, we want to host them both in a web-role (as website doesn't allow non-standard-HTTP(S) ports).

So is it feasible to host them both in a web-role, to keep the SignalR/web-interface capabilities but also use the binary WCF/`netTcpBinding` pattern?

### Edit:

Maybe I should've asked in the first place "[How to host both asp.net (for SignalR) and WCF (for netTcpBinding) in single web-role and wire them up to the hosting IIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34811555/how-to-host-both-asp-net-for-signalr-and-wcf-for-nettcpbinding-in-single-web)"

Answer (score 1):

As long as socket binding does not conflict - I cannot see why that should not be possible.

See here:
[What default port does WCF use for nettcp when hosted by IIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371567/what-default-port-does-wcf-use-for-nettcp-when-hosted-by-iis)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731810(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Maybe that's what I had to ask in the first place... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34811555/how-to-host-both-asp-net-for-signalr-and-wcf-for-nettcpbinding-in-single-web