# How to host both asp.net (for SignalR) and WCF (for netTcpBinding) in single web-role and wire them up to the hosting IIS?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, azure, iis, azure-web-roles

How do I host both `asp.net` (to use `SignalR` w/ Azure's backplane) and `WCF` service (for fast binary `netTcpBinding`) in web-role (extreme budget issues...)?

I suppose both must be self-hosted, but how to wire up each of them to the hosting `IIS` in the VM (I believe they both reside in the same app-domain)?

(It's a continuation of "[Is it possible to host both web/SignalR and WCF w/ netTcpBinding in a single web-role?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34793177/is-it-possible-to-host-both-web-signalr-and-wcf-w-nettcpbinding-in-a-single-web)")

Comment: If you're self hosting your apps, you do not use IIS and could go with a Worker Role (VM without IIS). That would have the applications running in separate processes - hence different app-domains.

Answer (score 0):

If you're self hosting your apps, you do not use IIS and could go with a Worker Role (VM without IIS).
That would have the applications running in separate processes - hence different app-domains.
You sepcify the listening port of you asp.net application in the OWIN start method - e.g. Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.Start("http://localhost:8080")

Comment: I don't think that a worker role can listen to inbound connections. Web server, such as IIS, must exist in the pipeline in order to serve clients in any case, so I can't see how it can be accomplished without web role and without wiring the services to the IIS.

Comment: Take a look here: http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/host-owin-in-an-azure-worker-role. The main difference between web and worker role is that a web role has IIS installed, a worker role has not.